# Inequality involving prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, primorial

If $p_k$ denotes the $k$ th prime then show that
$$p_k \cdot p_{k+1} > p_{k+2}.$$
$$$$
I think that Bertrand's pastulate and Bonse's inequality could be helpful but I exactly don't know how to use them?

Comment: Its trivial with Bertrand postulate because $p_k \ge 2$.  Are you sure you are allowed to use BP?  I think it wouldn't be hard to show there is an $M; p_{k+1} < M < p_{k+1}p_k$ were none of the $p_i$ divide $M$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $p_k\cdot p_{k+1}\geq 2p_{k+1}$

Answer (score 0):

You can prove this as follows
$P_{k+1}>P_k
\implies P_k\cdot P_{k+1}>P_k^2$

but we know there is always a prime between $a$ and $2a$[Bertrand's Postulate].
hence for $P_k>3$
$\implies P_k^2> P_{k+2}$

combining the 2 we get

$P_k\cdot P_{k+1}>P_{k+2}$